# How to make VSC use only TFVC and not git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, tfvc

In my Visual Studio Code, I use only TFVC for source control. But every time I open my source folder, the git also shows up and my TFVC. I have to "Close Repository" every time on the git and continue to checkin my changes to TFVC only.

How would I tell Visual Studio Code not to consider "git" as source control provider?

Comment: This would be so much easier to understand with a few well-made screenshots...

Comment: Try diabling Git as source control.Click
File>Preferences>Settings
Scroll down to git and change the 
"git.enabled": true to "git.enabled": false